# swipe to new nib

Tags: ios, uikit, uigesturerecognizer, nib, uiswipegesturerecognizer

I just want to be able to swipe to a new nib, but am getting stuck. My code builds properly with no errors or warnings, but nothing happens.

Here is my code

```
- (IBAction) handleSwipeGesture:(UIGestureRecognizer *) sener { 
        NSLog(@"swipe left");
    if(UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionLeft) {
        SecondDetailViewController *tempController = [[SecondDetailViewController alloc] 
         initWithNibName:@"SecondDetailView" 
          bundle:nil];
        newController = [tempController retain];
        [tempController release];
    }

}
```

The system sees that I am swiping (it gets logged) but it doesn't go to the new nib.
I'm not really married to my code, so if I need to completely rewrite this I'm OK.

Comment: Do you use navigation controller to display your view controllers?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you're handling swipe gesture inside a view controller (and you are using navigation controller), you should do something like this:

```
- (IBAction)handleSwipeGesture:(UISwipeGestureRecognizer *)sender { 
    if(sender.direction == UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionLeft) {
        NSLog(@"swipe left");
        SecondDetailViewController *tempController = [[SecondDetailViewController alloc]
                                  initWithNibName:@"SecondDetailView" bundle:nil];
        [self.navigationController pushViewController:tempController animated:YES];
        [tempController release];
    }
}
```

This line pushes `tempController` on top of the navigation controller:

```
[self.navigationController pushViewController:tempController animated:YES];
```

if you want to present `tempController` modally, you should call this instead:

```
[self presentModalViewController:tempController animated:YES];
```

Comment: This was actually off a SplitViewController. Is the code different for the SplitView versus NavigationController? While Ayoy's code builds technically correct (no errors), I don't even get anything with the log now!

Comment: oh and if it matters, this is using apple's "MultipleDetailView" project

Comment: You're not seeing anything in the log because I moved the debug output inside the `if` clause testing for swipe direction, and you're probably not swiping to the left :) Split view controller is just a container for two view controllers and it doesn't provide any API for view transitions. You can't even reference the split view controller from its child view controllers (to swap one of them with the new one as you swipe). You can, however, put a navigation controller as one of split view controller children and use it to manage views flow.

Comment: **note:** I'm assuming that you're handling swipe gesture inside a child view controller of your split view controller. Is this right?

Comment: Basically I'm doing a magazine, and a splitview was my first draft, and I was just being lazy and trying to redo that instead of building something new. If I do the swipe, I don't necessarily need the split. So should I just start from scratch and start with a nav controller?

Comment: Yes, I think Navigation-based application is the most popular template for a multi-view app. Then you start off with a navigation controller and pushing view controllers on top of it. Each view controller would have `navigationController` property by which you could push new controllers and pop old ones.

Comment: Hmm, back to the drawing board, but at least I know where to start from. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

You are not doing anything with the newController object after you create it. You need to either push it onto your nav controller, present it modally, or grab the view and put it on the screen.